# Java RMI performance issue – priorities one method

Tags: java, performance, rmi

I have an application in java with two services (A and B) communicating via RMI
10 method that service A can activate on B side
and 6 methods that service B can activate on A side
between this 6 methods I have one important method that I am checking performance for,
I am counting the difference of time before the RMI call until the start of the method on the other side (side A)
The time is usually around 0-4 ms, but sometime the time difference is jumping to around : 40,60 even 100 ms per call
Question:
1)  is there a way using RMI to give priority to one method (or thread) over the others?
2)  What can cause this instability? 
3)  What is the best performance rate can achieve using RMI on such application? 
4)  Other suggested solutions?

Thanks in advance,
Boaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) is there a way using RMI to give priority to one method (or thread) over the others?

There is no way to give an RMI method precedence over others. There is also no evidence here that it would do any good, as there is no evidence of contention problems. You can change the priority of any thread, but again absent evidence of contention there is no reason to believe it would help.

> 2) What can cause this instability?

The network, the DNS, the load at either end, the network load,...

> 3) What is the best performance rate can achieve using RMI on such application?

A meaningless question. What hardware? What network? What bandwidth? What latency? What load? How long do the methods take to execute locally under no load, or rather only that load?

> 4) Other suggested solutions?

There are many ways to communicate over a network but they all invoke a networks DNS, a bandwidth, a latency, hardware at either end, a load, ... All the same factors.

RMI performance is mostly Serialization performance in terms of CPU and bandwidth, and DNS performance in terms of latency.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running the 2 services on the same PC (must separate them, so one can work without the other)
Therefore I ignore the network latency

Comment: There's still network latency involved in the DNS lookups. Java does both forward and reverse DNS when you open a socket.

Comment: Cam I avoid the DNS lookups while using RMI?

Comment: No you can't. They are deep in the implementation of sockets. But they only happen when a connection is opened. You can control that a bit via RMI system properties: see the RMI Home Page. There are properties that control connection pooling at the client.